# the path for phpmyadmin

Tags: linux, centos, unix

i have www doc in html folder. i go to 192.168.1.1/phpmyadmin to pull it up. but when i ftp there i dont see any phpmyadmin folder under html folder. how can i find where phpmyadmin folder is? i am using centos

Answer (score 4):

You don't see any *phpmyadmin* folder when accessing your hosting via FTP because it's an **alias**, some kind of *virtual folder*.

If you have an **SSH** access to your hosting, **phpMyAdmin** is usually located in **/usr/share/phpmyadmin**. If you don't find it there, try to *locate* it :

```
$ locate phpmyadmin
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found that many distributions would rather install an application's web files within /usr/lib or /usr/share as a convention. As such, you may want to verify your apache configuration files to determine the exact path.

In this case, most likely you'll have the phpmyadmin apache directives within a file located within /etc/apache2/conf.d or /etc/httpd/conf.d or the like. The configuration file will have a  statement which will detail the location of your files.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably in /var/www/html/phpmyadmin, but take a look at your Apache configuration files to make sure (try grepping for phpmyadmin in all your Apache config directories).

Comment: i tried $ > grep phpmyadmin. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

On CentOS, check: /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

If not there, do a

```
$whereis phpMyAdmin
```